# OpenCV: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, face-recognition

I am creating a face recognition system using Python and OpenCV on these versions:

- Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
- Anaconda 4.3.23
- OpenCV 3.3.0

When I try to train the face recognizer:

```
face_recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Update:

I've tried to do this:

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.3.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Also:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.3.0
```

And I still have the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, you have to follow this tutorial [OpenCV with extra modules](https://blog.talentica.com/2017/08/29/opencv-with-extra-modules/).

The essential steps are:

- Go to C:/PythonXX/lib/site-packeges (the site-packages folder where your python is installed), and delete cv2.pyd if present.
- Download OpenCV with extra modules
- Create a Visual Studio project with CMake
- Open Python IDLE and enter import cv2. If there is no error, then the installation is successful.

Answer (score 2):

The Menpo project does not have an installer for OpenCV 3.3. The Menpo project is up to 3.1 on macOS and Windows, and 3.2 on Linux. See the [Anaconda package](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) for that description and also the [list of files](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) for the installer versions. Actually, you can check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3) for Menpo's OpenCV3 build and grab the files yourself. You can change the build files to suit your system if needed.

I'm not sure if your `pip` attempt includes a typo or not---the correct PyPI package `wheel` file with the contrib module is `opencv_contrib_python` not `opencv_python+contrib`, as shown at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python). Note that if you're not using Windows the GUI features of OpenCV will not work with the `pip` installer, including `imshow()` and other similar features.

You'd be better served just removing and reinstalling fresh *with* the contrib modules instead of trying to build them in later.

Answer (score 1):

While I was looking for the same solution, I tried out many methods which don't work well with successfully installing OpenCV along with the extra modules i.e., OpenCV Contrib.

Apparently, while using `pip install opencv-python` windows platforms usually download only OpenCV without the extra modules!

What works, is stable and easy to install:

1. Download the integrated 'whl' file containing both OpenCV and it's Contrib files, which would be like 'opencv_python‑3.4.3+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl' which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).
2. Install using `pip install <whl filename>`

I have tried other methods which are unreliable such as the solution suggested by @RoyaumeIX, however ended up with failure.

So is it with using

```
pip install opencv
pip install opencv-contrib
```

Installing `opencv-contrib` does not properly register the `opencv` package.

I strongly suggest that you directly download the official whl file and install it.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem but it got resolved by following these steps:

1. start anaconda navigator
2. open CMD.exe prompt, hope you see this  `**(base) C:\Users\acer>**` this may be different for you
3. write these command >>>`**pip install opencv-contrib-python**`
4. Now you can run your code as check!! I have runned my code in Spyder in base enviroment and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

this should fix the problem

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Comment: Good evenning, I had the same problem, I managed using these installers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my using python 2.7 and opencv 3.3.0
 working in code

```
cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, as were found at [OpenCV forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/175913/attribute-error-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-face/?answer=175916#post-id-175916) (and [same at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453597/8366223)), works well for me:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv_contrib_python
```

And in cv2 version 4.0.0 face recogniser can be created by using different function name, as [mentionted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843755/8366223):

```
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
face_recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
face_recognizer = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
```