# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: opencv, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3

I tried to install opencv3.4.0 on a raspberry3 following this guide: https://www.life2coding.com/install-opencv-3-4-0-python-3-raspberry-pi-3/

Now the problem is that I could not figure out why python3 gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

This happens, whenever I try to execute

`face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

I already installed opencv3.4.0 and also the additional modules: opencv3.4.0_contrib. I know that "face" needs to be part of the extra modules. Still I cannot figure out what causes this error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer().

Comment: Still returns the same error because 'face' is not detected

Comment: How did you install the contrib package?

Comment: wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.0.zip                     unzip opencv_contrib.zip

Comment: I am installing it using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. I will let you know soon!

Comment: I think you mean pip3, right?

Comment: It works now. I installed the contrib package using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. If python 3 is your default version then you can use `pip` otherwise use `pip3`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but I am still getting the same error..

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out. It works for me though!

Comment: I will try to build opencv_contrib like it is described here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib but I am struggling to find out <opencv_source_directory>. Do you know what path that might be? Apparently it is not the unzip opencv-3.4.0 folder..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288224/opencv-attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-face)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it working. I just used pip for both installations:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```