# Rust binding for OpenCV seems to be missing the face module

Tags: opencv, rust

I'm using [`opencv`](https://docs.rs/crate/opencv/0.47.0) as OpenCV bindings for rust and I'm trying to implement an EigenFaceRecogniser system. On docs.rs, the `opencv::face` module is listed inside the `opencv` crate. However, when I build my code, I get the error:

```
could not find face in opencv
```

I'm not really sure what's causing this as the `face` module is clearly listed in the documentation but for some reason I cannot use it. If anybody who has used these bindings before or knows anything about what could be going wrong could help, it would be appreciated.

I'm using OpenCV version 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to enable the `contrib` feature for the `opencv` package.

While I was writing the above question, I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274439/attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-face) post asking about OpenCV having no `face` module in python. The solution to that question was to install the `opencv-contrib-python` package so I tried enabling the `contrib` feature in the `opencv` crate and it compiled. I thought I'd post this question anyway just in case somebody else was having this issue.