# How can I fix the 'module cv2 has no attribute face' error in OpenCV-Python module?

Tags: python, opencv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ankan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\VS Code Projects\Attendace_management_system\AMS_Run.py", line 565, in trainimg
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
                 ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

I have installed opencv properly but still getting this error.

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729541/getting-attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-face

Comment: @Ankan Ghosh. What are you running on pc or arm devices such as Raspberry Pi, Rock, etc? Also OpenCV version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check OpenCV version: Verify the version of OpenCV installed on your system. You can do this by running the following code :

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

Or you can try to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling and re-installing opencv

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```